# RSS feed ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") Chrome compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, activexobject, xmldom

I get, format and display a RSS feed usingt he below code. I want to make it Chrome compatible. Unfortunately i've used ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"), anyone know how i comply with Chroem (and probably majority) browser?

I have tried the following if statment to steer non-ie browsers to alt code but the alt code doesnt work - i havnt managed to populate the rss var.

```
if (window.DOMParser) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString("RSS.xml", "text/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer
{
    var rss = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    rss.async = false
    rss.load("RSS.xml")
}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var sText = "" 
var i=0 
var iNews=0 
var rss = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") 
rss.async = false 
rss.load("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/england/rss.xml")

function GetNewsSource(){ 
var itemNodes = rss.selectNodes("/rss/channel/item") 
var iMax = itemNodes.length

sText = itemNodes.item(iNews).getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).text 
myTicker.href = itemNodes.item(iNews).getElementsByTagName("link").item(0).text 
ticker() 
iNews+=1 
if(iNews==iMax){ 
iNews=0 
} 
window.setTimeout("GetNewsSource()", (90*sText.length +4000)) 
}

function ticker(){ 
i+=1 
myTicker.innerText = sText.substring(0,i) + " _" 
if(i<sText.length){ 
window.setTimeout("ticker()",90) 
} 
else{ 
i=0 
} 
} 
</script>

</head> 
<body bgcolor="#B10000" text="#FFFFFF" link="#FFFFCC" vlink="#FFFFCC" alink="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onLoad="GetNewsSource()"> 
<a id="myTicker" href="" target="_parent"></a> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: I am not confident with Javascript - not sure what to do with this spec doc. I have edited the question with an attempt at navigating around the non-ie code. Any idea what solution is?